# Firebase web. No signInWithUsernameAndPassword function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am very confused about firebase web because when I create an auth using firebase.auth() then try to call a method directly from the firebase documentation, signInWithUsernameAndPassword, it does not work. I am using 
webstorm and is says it is an unrecognized method.

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBbmdeersid6XSA4kh_TYsGgVSgVF5BrFs",
    authDomain: "eraticators-73723.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://eraticators-73723.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "eraticators-73723",
    storageBucket: "eraticators-73723.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "782651564720"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const txtEmail = document.getElementById("user");
const txtPassword = document.getElementById("password");
const btnLogin = document.getElementById("btnLogin");

btnLogin.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    firebase.auth().signInWithUsernameAndPassword(email, pass);

});
```

that is my javascript file. The only suggested functions are signInViaPopup() and signInViaRedirect(). Why is there not signInWithUsernameAndPassword function when that is exactly what the documentation says to use????

Comment: You also need to enable Email/Password option in `firebase console -> authentication -> sign-in method.`

Answer (score 0):

`signInWithUsernameAndPassword` does not exist. Firebase Auth does not support sign in with username and password. It only supports sign in with email and password. The equivalent method is `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.
The Firebase docs and references should not mention the former at all.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check have you enabled authentication with Email/Password.
if you didn't enable it.
Follow the path given below:-

```
firebase console -> authentication -> sign-in method.
```

and enable signIn with email/password

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the script auth tag in the html.